# Creating "barriers" around the viewing area of a tkinter canvas object

Tags: python, tkinter, newline, python-3.5, tkinter-canvas

Okay, so I have sort of a unique situation here, so bear with me. I want to be able to create so called "barriers" around the *viewing area* (the part of the canvas visible to the user) of a tkinter canvas object. For example, take a look at the screenshots below (based on the MCVE at the end):

[image: Issue]

As you can see in the image above, the line currently goes ***outside*** the viewing area of the canvas when the user reaches the end. However, **that is not what I want.** Instead, I want that whenever the user reaches the end of the canvas's visible area, a "barrier" gets hot, and upon contact, **a carriage return occurs**, and the line(s) continue(s) on from there. So instead of the above, what I really want is this:

[image: What should be happening]

Here is the MCVE I used to take the above screenshots:

```
import tkinter as TK

xold = None
yold = None

class canvas(TK.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root, *args, **kwargs):
        # Initialize a tkinter frame widget
        TK.Frame.__init__(self, root, width = 800, height = 850, *args, **kwargs)
        self.root = self.winfo_toplevel()
        self.bg = "white"
        self.width, self.height = 850, 800
        self.canvwidth, self.canvheight = 10000, 10000
        # Set up the canvas and its corresponding scrollbars
        self.canvas = TK.Canvas(root, width=850, height=800,
                                 bg=self.bg, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness = 5, highlightbackground = 'brown', highlightcolor = 'brown')
        self.hscroll = TK.Scrollbar(root, command=self.canvas.xview,
                                    orient=TK.HORIZONTAL)
        self.vscroll = TK.Scrollbar(root, command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=self.hscroll.set,
                               yscrollcommand=self.vscroll.set)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1, minsize=0)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1, minsize=0)
        # Add the scrollbars into the root window
        self.canvas.grid(padx=1, pady=1, row=0,
                column=0, rowspan=1, columnspan=1, sticky = 'news')
        self.vscroll.grid(padx=1, pady=1, row=0,
                column=1, rowspan=1, columnspan=1, sticky='news')
        self.hscroll.grid(padx=1, pady=1, row=1,
                column=0, rowspan=1, columnspan=1, sticky='news')
        # Call the `reset` method of the canvas class
        self.reset()
        # Bind the `line` method to the 'l' key of the users keyboard (as an example of what I want)
        self.root.bind('<l>', self.line)

    def reset(self, canvwidth=None, canvheight=None, bg = None):
        ###############################################################################################################################
        # This adds the scrollbars themselves to the canvas and adapts them to the canvas's size (in this case, 10000 x 10000 pixels) #
        ###############################################################################################################################

        if canvwidth:
            self.canvwidth = canvwidth
        if canvheight:
            self.canvheight = canvheight
        if bg:
            self.bg = bg
        self.canvas.config(bg=bg,
                        scrollregion=(-self.canvwidth//2, -self.canvheight//2,
                                       self.canvwidth//2, self.canvheight//2))
        self.canvas.xview_moveto(0.5*(self.canvwidth - self.width + 30) /
                                                               self.canvwidth)
        self.canvas.yview_moveto(0.5*(self.canvheight- self.height + 30) /
                                                              self.canvheight)

    def line(self, event):
        ########################################################################################################
        # Create a short, horizontal, black line on every press of the user's 'l' key (as an example to go by) #
        ########################################################################################################
        global xold, yold
        if xold != None and yold != None:
            pass
        else:     
            xold, yold = 0, 0
        self.canvas.create_line(xold, yold, xold+30, yold, smooth = TK.TRUE, width = 1, capstyle = TK.ROUND, joinstyle = TK.ROUND, fill = 'black')
        xold = xold+30
        yold = yold

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create a window, and provide that window to the canvas class as the root window
    root = TK.Tk()
    root.geometry('900x850')
    canvas(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

**Is it possible to add this ability to the MCVE above using tkinter? If so, how would I get started on trying to implement it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are actually trying to do (especially trying to constrain drawing in the displayed region while you provide a very large canvas with scrollbars).

For the simplest case, all you need is a bound value and to test `xold` against it

```
if xold > 440:
    xold = -410
    yold += 30
```

If you want to take into account the current displayed area, you have to combine information from canvas `scrollregion` and `xview` methods. The first return the bounds of the canvas and former the relative position of the displayed aera in the scrollregion.

```
    scroll = list(map(int,self.canvas["scrollregion"].split()))
    xview = self.canvas.xview()
    leftbound = scroll[0] + xview[1] * (scroll[2]-scroll[0])
    if xold > leftbound:
        rightbound = scroll[0] + xview[0] * (scroll[2]-scroll[0])
        xold = rightbound
        yold += 30
```